# Cant install xp with along with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, bios, bsod

Hey guys am trying to install windows xp on my system...I have already installed windows 7 on my pc which works fine.

When i booted from the installation disk to install xp ..Firstly it shows the windows installing process 
then it throws me a blue screen `(BSOD)` which is like

[image: the blue screen error].

After some [research](https://superuser.com/questions/211582/unable-to-install-windows-xp-blue-screen-error-pops-up-before-starting-window) i have found that this maybe due to some bios settings.

So i have made some changes in bios like

[image: the changes]

But when i tried install it again the error is repeating again and again..

What should i do actually ??..Do i need to update any bios settings ??..Any help would be appreciated..Thanx

Here is my motherboard

http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPLAMPS/

Driver page

http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/P5KPLAMPS/HelpDesk_Download/

Manual

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5KPL-AM_PS/E4734_P5KPL-AM-PS_V3.zip

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason to get this error is that windows has a problem finding the disk it is trying to install itself on.

This can have several causes, but you posted that you already had win7 installed. That probably means a system which is not decades old, which has SATA and which is probably set to AHCI mode.  If this is the case then you can not install windows XP in the same AHCI controller without adding drives to XP.

I wrote [a post on this here](https://superuser.com/questions/828497/windows-xp-requires-bios-ide-setting-to-boot-up-how-to-fix-this).

Basically, you either:
 - Set the whole system to AHCI (best option).
 - Then install windows XP, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> to load the AHCI drivers from a floppy during installation.
 - Then install windows 7

Why?

- AHCI for best performance and least problems.
- The floppy with drivers (or a slipstreamed XP disc) to load to SATA/AHCI drivers for XP
- Win7 last. This because Mand how to keep previous versions working).

## Alternative:

- Set the BIOS (which is for all OS's. Thus influences XP and win7) to ancient legacy mode.
- Install XP.
- Install windows 7 (which will work but which will miss some features, such as hot-swapping. NCQ (which will hurt SSD performance) etc etc.

Note that you can not just change Legacy IDE to AHCI after you installed the OS. For windows 7 it is possible if you [carefully follow the right steps](https://superuser.com/questions/432022/ahci-mode-gave-me-two-boot-options). For XP it means reinstalling.

Comment: ..could u tell me how can i set the whole system to ahci ..i didnt find an option on the bios

Comment: If it is not in the BIOS as something which you can change then it is either always set to legacy mode, or always set to AHCI. Whichever the manufacturer decided. Which of these should be mentioned in the motherboard manual/specs.

Comment: ..see i only can see the options like s- ata, p- ata..from the storage config..actually am stuck ..do i need to download essenstial drivers ??>.is my system already set to ahsi mode ??

Comment: ..i dont see any options named ahci or anything on my bios ..i have set my configuration with s - ata ...but when i proceed it shows me error..plz help me

Comment: ..do i need to download the  drivers for xp and put it on usb and load drivers by clicking f6 during xp instalation

Comment: @AvinashBabu press escape to get out of the screen you're on, look through all the options in the BIOS for the things Hennes has mentioned (AHCI, Legacy). Comment here what is your motherboard model so we can find the manual, or better just link directly to the manual, and we can look in the manual.

Answer (score -1):

That isn't   BIOS related. It is an issue with a Windows installation. And if you tweak the BIOS to boot off whatever hard drive, if it ever tries to load that Windows then it'll give that BSOD. You should google the details of the BSOD e.g. BSOD pci.sys  And you would then see that -nowhere- does the information there say 'BIOS'.  BSODs are almost never from the or to do with a setting in the BIOS.

You could install XP on one hard drive (booting off that hard drive to do it)

Install Windows 7 on another hard drive, (also, booting off that hard drive).

And then tell your BIOS to boot off whichever hard drive you want depending on which Windows you want.

If you get any BSOD there doing that then it's definitely nothing to do with different Windows versions

As for your BSOD, it's most likely nothing to do with mixing Windows versions. Maybe you just have an issue with a Windows installation. Try the method I mention, to simplify things.

Perhaps You could later try to later boot Windows 7 and have it detect XP, i'm not sure if it can but you could try it.  If you do try that method, then youu'd be choosing which Windows version to boot from a menu. It's not clear from you if you did that.  No doubt that if doing that method, XP won't see 7, but 7 might see XP. So you'd install XP first, then(the later windows OS, so) Win 7 after.

Comment: see i didnt get what you mentioned..how can i change my drive from the bios ??..actually when i try installation it isnt proceeding due to this blue screen

Comment: @AvinashBabu personally i've never seen a BSOD fixed by a BIOS setting. But it looks like Hennes has, so see what he says, as BIOS tweaks are very easy and quick to do.

Comment: see i just didnt get what he said actually ...is already ahsi mode enabled  ??  how can i overcome this solution..

Comment: @AvinashBabu Hennes is saying that you have 2 choices either A)Change the BIOS from AHCI to Legacy  OR B)Stick with AHCI and hit F6 when XP asks to and give it AHCI drivers. (You could do that with an external floppy drive).  Or putting them in the correct location of a CD you make.  I have never had the issue you describe but perhaps AHCI drivers are on the support link for your motherboard under drivers.  If you can't see those options AHCI or Legacy in the BIOS or manual.. and can't change them then you have to go the driver method as described. So look on the drivers page for your MBRD.

Comment: @barloop ..here is my motherboard http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPLAMPS/

Comment: @barloop as i dont have an option ahci from my bios ..i think i would need to do the driver method ..since i havnt done it before ..i dont know how to do it actually....could you help me ?

Comment: @barlop..have you found any useful information ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu some.. here's a driver page if it helps http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/P5KPLAMPS/HelpDesk_Download/  and here's the BIOS manual http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5KPL-AM_PS/E4734_P5KPL-AM-PS_V3.zip

Comment: @barloop ..thanx yeah so my question is how do i install them..now am on windows 7..how can i install those drivers for xp from bios

Comment: @AvinashBabu I don't know where the AHCI driver is(if there is one), and I don't know where the setting is in the BIOS. Maybe Hennes or somebody else knows. But the link you gave me of MBRD model, and the links I gave you, to the BIOS manual and the Driver page will help people help you. I have now added those links to your question

Comment: @barloop .actually there is an option to load drivers while installing by pressing f6..i have copied one driver to my usb actually..but it didnt let me choose the file while the installation.

Comment: True. XP was designed to look for drivers in two places. 1) On the XP installation disk in a very specific way (check slipstreaming). 2) Via a floppy (not on a disk, on a pen drive, on a CD, ... on a regular old fashioned floppy connected via a floppy cable or for four specific USB-floppy models). Last century this was fine. A modern OS has many more options but XP is not modern. It used these ancient methods.

Comment: @Hennes i dont have a floopy drive on my pc actually .it would be really helpful if you advice me on what should i do next..now i have enabled s - ata mode actually..it shows the same error ..is this any disk problem?..please help me

Comment: First things first: Where is the disk that you are installing on connected to? To the ICH7's SATA bus or the 40 pins IDE connectors? And which XP version are you installing? (See the warning on page 1-23 of your manual where it requires at least XP SP1 to use Serial ATA). If you are using a PATA bus: WHich does are there and how are they connected. Are they properly set as single or as master/slave? (If have seen an OS barf on an improper setup while the BIOS 'helpfully' allowed it).

Comment: @AvinashBabu yes I am well aware that XP has an option to load drivers via two methods. I thought your problem was you couldn't find the drivers?  You either buy an external floppy drive. OR, you put the drivers in the correct directory of the CD(i.e. make a custom image). If it's not urgent then you could just buy an external floppy drive. But what driver are you using?

Comment: @Hennes am trying to install windows xp pro version..

Comment: @barlop will this work fine if i use any other installation disk of xp /?

Comment: But which XP pro? The original? The version with SP1 already integrated? The version with SP2 already integrated? The version with SP3 already integrated?

Comment: @Hennes  i dont know actually ..where do i find that ??..

Comment: I just created one.  [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18510/cannot-install-xp-with-along-with-windows-7).